# Global Variables not working - Android

Tags: android, global-variables

I have created a class called CommentInfo that extends Application. This class is suppose to hold global variables for my comments. I have declared it in the Manifest file but it still causes the app to crash. CommentInfo is not inside the DashboardActivity.

**COMMENT INFO CLASS**

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Application;

    class CommentInfo extends Application {

          private String commentID;
          private int gatheredComments;

          public String getCommentID(){
            return commentID;
          }
          public void setCommentID(String c){
            commentID = c;
          }

          public int getGatheredComments(){
                return gatheredComments;
              }
              public void setGatheredComments(int forNumber){
                gatheredComments = forNumber;
              }
        }
```

I try to access the variables in another activity called DashboardActivity here is a small example,

**DASHBOARD ACTIVITY**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //This is how I call the class
            final CommentInfo CommentInfoClass = ((CommentInfo)getApplicationContext());
            //This is how I set the variables
            CommentInfoClass.setCommentID("0");

    }
}
```

Then I declare the CommentInfo name inside the Manifest file as this,
This is the only application tag I have in the Manifest file, it wraps around all of my Activities.

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
<application 
        android:name="CommentInfo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Then this is the error code I receive from my LogCat,

**LOG CAT ERROR**

```
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.CommentInfo: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:529)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4442)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:963)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:948)
08-23 00:01:13.486: E/AndroidRuntime(24880):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:520)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your CommentInfo class extend Application? Just make it a regular class.

```
class CommentInfo {

      public CommentInfo() {}

      private String commentID;
      private int gatheredComments;

      public String getCommentID(){
        return commentID;
      }
      public void setCommentID(String c){
        commentID = c;
      }

      public int getGatheredComments(){
            return gatheredComments;
          }
          public void setGatheredComments(int forNumber){
            gatheredComments = forNumber;
          }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
CommentInfo info = new CommentInfo();
info.setCommentID("0");
```

Comment: I was following a tutorial and that is how they did it so I followed that. I believe the reasoning behind it is so the variables could be used in every activity within the application. Fortunately in my circumstances I don't need the variables to be used across the application. So this method works for me, so far that is lol. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to use the constants across activities, there's actually a simple solution. You can make this class an abstract class that just holds constants for the names of the variables that you'll need. Then, use those names as keys for a Bundle and pass the Bundle around to different activities

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<application 
        android:name="CommentInfo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >`

with

`<application 
        android:name="<PACKAGENAME>.CommentInfo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >`

Inside the CommentInfo @Override OnCreate as well

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

   }
```

Comment: by <PACKAGENAME> you mean my actual package name like com.example? If so do I keep the <> brackets?

Comment: No just write the package name, In case if Application Application file is in the same package of Activity just use .CommentInfo.

Answer (score 0):

public class DataHolderClass {

```
private static DataHolderClass dataObject= null;

private DataHolderClass()

{
    // left blank intentionally
}


public static DataHolderClass getInstance()

{
    if(dataObject==null)

        dataObject = new DataHolderClass();|

    return dataObject;

}
```

private String commentID;
      private int gatheredComments;

```
  public String getCommentID(){
    return commentID;
  }
  public void setCommentID(String c){
    this.commentID = c;
  }

  public int getGatheredComments(){
        return gatheredComments;
      }
      public void setGatheredComments(int forNumber){
        this.gatheredComments = forNumber;
      }
```

}

now in your activity class to set values use:
DataHolderClass.getInstance().setCommandId(Your String);

and to get values from  dataholderclass

DataHolderClass.getInstance().commentID .